# Running model.fit multiple times for an LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm, prediction, forecasting

I have time-series histogram data from many separate machine runs (see [this post for detail](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559528/many-to-many-time-series-prediction-problem)).

I am working to train an LSTM in order to predict the final histogram in a machine run based on the past histogram data. I've been struggling to understand how to do this while separating machine run data.

I'm thinking that maybe a solution is to simply run `model.fit()` while looping through each `run_id`:

```py
n_features = 42
n_timesteps = 9
groups = df.groupby(by="run_id")
for key, group in groups:
    # training features
    group = group[moisture_dist_columns].to_numpy()
    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    # Here I am creating an X array with sequences of length n_timesteps
    for i in range(n_timesteps, len(group)):
        X_train.append(group[i - n_timesteps : i])
        y_train.append(group[i])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
    X_train = X_train.reshape((-1, n_timesteps, n_features))
    y_train = y_train.reshape((-1, 1, 42))
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=16)
```

When I do this, I can see the validation loss is reducing, so maybe it's working? Based on [this short discussion](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67411/does-keras-model-fit-remember-learning-rate-when-called-multiple-times) I think it may be okay.

Is this a reasonable thing to do if I want to train the LSTM with the information from each machine `run_id`?

Another option I am thinking of besides using a for loop is to build a generator that passes each run_id as a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than separate each machine run's data, I loop through each machine run, appending the sliding windows:

```py
def split_sequences(df, n_timesteps_in, n_timesteps_out):
    X, y = list(), list()
    groups = df.groupby("user_id")
    for _, group in groups:
        for i in range(len(group)):
            # find the end of this pattern
            end_ix = i + n_timesteps_in
            out_end_ix = end_ix + n_timesteps_out
            # check if we are beyond the dataset
            if end_ix + 1 > len(group):
                break
            # gather input and output parts of the pattern
            seq_x, seq_y = (
                group.iloc[i:end_ix][moisture_dist_columns].to_numpy(),
                group.iloc[end_ix:out_end_ix][moisture_dist_columns].to_numpy(),
            X.append(seq_x)
            y.append(seq_y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```